# Store jquery result into a array (or something like that) to be used by another javascript

Tags: jquery

Appreciate some insight given the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>video_player</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "'><img src='" + $(this).attr("ows_snapshot_file_location") + "' width=120 height=90><strong>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "</strong><br /><br />" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "<em>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_length") + "</em></a><br />";
        //{missing code}//
    });
}
</script>
```

What code should I enter inside the //{missing code}// such that I can store the variable 'lihtml' into a array that can be used in any javascript? (I wish to use document.write() to display the "lihtml" variable.

**UPDATE 1:**
After taking minus4 consideration, the code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var glob;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>video_player</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                           <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
});

function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "'><img src='" + $(this).attr("ows_snapshot_file_location") + "' width=120 height=90><strong>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "</strong><br /><br />" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "<em>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_length") + "</em></a><br />";
        glob.append(liHtml);
    });
}
</script>
```

and at the other part of the same document, I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(glob);
</script>
```

and now, I receive the 'undefined' error. Any insight?

Comment: Since jQuery *is* JavaScript, replacing that with `document.write(lihtml)` will do. Otherwise, please clarify what you mean by 'another JavaScript'. Is it another (external?) file, another user session, an userscript?

Comment: @YiJiang, The another Javascript that I am referring to was another <script> </script> probably at the other part of the same file.

Comment: `lihtml` will only be in scope for the `processResult` function. If you want to use the variable outside of the function you'd need to declare it differently. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
var glob = [];
```

then -

```
function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "'><img src='" + $(this).attr("ows_snapshot_file_location") + "' width=120 height=90><strong>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "</strong><br /><br />" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "<em>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_length") + "</em></a><br />";
        glob.push(liHtml);
    });
}
```

and for output -

```
document.write(glob.join(""));
```

That should build up a dynamic array of your html strings, that can be output via the `array.join` method. I think the problem with you original code is you're using `append' on a normal JavaScript variable when it is a jQuery specific function. Adding the content to a dynamic array should have the same effect.

Comment: Tried but this time, there is no error message, just a blank screen.

Comment: If you add `console.log(liHtml)` after the `glob.push(liHtml)` line are you getting any data returned?

Comment: Still the same thing - a blank screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to look in the console of your browser - I suspect you may be getting no data returned. You could also try `alert(liHtml)` and see if you get any alert messages.

Comment: +1 no alert message. can tell me how to get that data returned?

Comment: You're either getting no data back at all or the function that loops through your data is not working. You could `alert(xData.responseXML)` to see what you're getting back. Although you'd be best logging to the console as that would allow you to explore any objects returned.

Comment: there is nothing shown too. By the way. the `alert(xData.responseXML)` is it put inside the `function processResult(xData, status)` or put where?

Comment: `alert(xData.responseXML)` should go inside `processResult` if `xData` is empty then it looks as if you are getting no data returned.

Comment: In that case, I have put it correctly but I still get that nothing is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should directly call any other javascript fonction from processResult function so you don't have to store data anymore. So missing code could be something like

```
printMe(liHtml,'SomePlace');
```

Or directly add the document.write function there?

```
document.write(liHtml);
```

Or maybe can you give more details about the kind of js you want to call?

Comment: Please see my comments for YiJiang. Thanks.

Comment: OK.So as they have already said, what you need is to declare a global variable so you need to put `var liHtml` before the  `$(document).ready(...)` and just use `liHtml = ....` in the ` processResult` function

Comment: Yes, I put a global variable but it return me a 'undefined' error message.

Comment: Maybe you call the other script before this one?It must be called after.

Comment: Yes, I call all other script before this one cause I know that the variable need to contain data before it can be displayed by this one.

Comment: So I think the reason you have undefined is just because the ajax is not yet complete before the script to display the variable is called. For example if you try to declare glob as `var glob = "<a href='#'>Click</a>"` you won't have the undefined anymore. That's why I say the best solution is to create a function called ONLY when the AJAX data are ready

Comment: I don't get it. The function is called when completed `complete: processResult,` inside the `$(document).ready(function()`. Have I coded wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

you could create a global variable.

or if you wan to caryy this around multiple pages then try http://blog.reybango.com/2010/04/08/alternative-client-side-storage-using-sessvars-js/   it will store the data for you wihin the browser, across pages etc

then using jquery you can say $('#idofdivorspan').html('');